# Override module method to extend functionality then import the updated module from another file

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add to pandas a custom function without touching the pandas package. I tried to following:

`extra_pandas.py`:

```
from pandas import *
class DataFrame2(pandas.core.frame.DataFrame):
    def new_function(self):
        print("I exist")
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame = DataFrame2
```

`my_script.py`:

```
import extra_pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
print(df.new_function())
```

It appears not to work and I can't figure out what is wrong. I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'new_function'

What am I missing?

Thank you very much

**Update:**
I gave the Alternative solution a try and wanted to patch all pandas function in a loop using this snippet:

```
patch_function = [read_csv, read_json, read_html, read_clipboard, read_excel,
                  read_hdf, read_feather, read_parquet, read_msgpack,
                  read_stata, read_sas, read_pickle, read_sql, read_gbq]

for func in patch_function:
    orig_func = func

    def patch(*args, **kwargs):
        return DataFrame(orig_func(*args, **kwargs))

    func = patch
```

But this is not working. Any idea why?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution 1

You cannot patch but you cen replace:

`extra_pandas.py`:

```
from pandas import *

class DataFrame2(DataFrame):
    def new_function(self):
        print("I exist")

DataFrame = DataFrame2
```

`my_script.py`:

```
import extra_pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('furniture.csv'))
print(df.new_function())
```

Output:

```
I exist
```

### Solution 2

Just import you own class:

`extra_pandas.py`:

```
import pandas as pd

class DataFrame2(pd.DataFrame):
    def new_function(self):
        print("I exist")
```

`my_script.py`:

```
import pandas as pd
from extra_pandas import DataFrame2

df = DataFrame2(pd.read_csv('example.csv'))
print(df.new_function())
```

Output:

```
I exist
```

`DataFrame` takes another dataframe as input for making a new dataframe.

### Explanation

You try to monkey patch the `DataFrame` class. This does not work. This is likely due to the fact that is largely written in Cython, hence compiled to a C extension. This interferes with your attempt to monkey patch.

### Alternative

Or monkey patch `read_csv()`.

`extra_pandas.py`:

```
import pandas as pd

class DataFrame2(pd.DataFrame):
    def new_function(self):
        print("I exist")


orig_read_csv=pd.read_csv

def my_read_csv(*args, **kwargs):
    return DataFrame2(orig_read_csv(*args, **kwargs))

pd.read_csv = my_read_csv
```

`my_script.py`:

```
import pandas as pd

import extra_pandas

df = pd.read_csv('furniture.csv')
print(df.new_function())
```

Output:

```
I exist
```

Comment: First thank you for the answer. This isnt really user friendly though because you can't just continue using the same syntax as before. Is there any other way around it without patching the pandas module itself?

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. I thought about it but it is less general and would require to patch all read_* functions to teach them new_function. I guess in this context there is no alternative other than patching directly to pandas

Comment: Your solution 1 has the caveat that you need pd.DataFrame(*) around all functions returning a DataFrame. too bad that it is pre-compiled