# Programatically monkey patch multiple functions in Python based on list of functions

Tags: python, pandas

I try to monkey patch several functions looping over a list of functions like this:

```
from pandas import *


class DataFrame(DataFrame):
    def new_function(self):
        print("I exist")


patch_function = [read_csv, read_json, read_html, read_clipboard, read_excel,
                  read_hdf, read_feather, read_parquet, read_msgpack,
                  read_stata, read_sas, read_pickle, read_sql, read_gbq]

for func in patch_function:
    orig_func = func

    def patch(*args, **kwargs):
        return DataFrame(orig_func(*args, **kwargs))

    func = patch

df = read_csv('example.csv')
df.new_function()
```

However, this seems not to work. Could someone tell me why it is not working and how this could be done? Thank you!

Comment: What/why are you trying to do with this? Unclear from the example what the goal is.

Comment: I want to patch DataFrame in pandas but I can’t. I was told it is precompiled and can’t be monkey patched on runtime. So I will patch the functions using DataFrama. But since I apply the same patch to many functions I want to do this in a loop. See also my initial question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47922816/override-module-method-to-extend-functionality-then-import-the-updated-module-fr

Answer (score 1):

Instead of polluting with all of the pandas functions, I found it easier to use the list of strings for the function names. I think your issue was actually updating the base functions on the `pd` module - hopefully this makes sense and does what you need/expect.

```
#patched_pandas.py

import pandas as pd

class DataFrame2(pd.DataFrame):
    def new_function(self):
        print("I exist")


patch_function = ['read_csv', 'read_json', 'read_html', 'read_clipboard', 'read_excel',
                  'read_hdf', 'read_feather', 'read_msgpack',
                  'read_stata', 'read_sas', 'read_pickle', 'read_sql']

for func in patch_function:
    orig_func = getattr(pd, func)

    def patch(func):
        def patched(*args, **kwargs):
            return DataFrame2(func(*args, **kwargs))
        return patched

    setattr(pd, func, patch(orig_func))
```

Then to use, just import and grab the modified version of pandas.

```
#main.py (or wherever)
from patched_pandas import pd

df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
df.new_function()
```

Comment: Thanks and cool idea but after patching I want to import this python file from another python script and work as if I just imported pandas. So basically just share a patched_pandas.py and then import it as: import patched_pandas as pd

Comment: @doom4 I have added an edit for that - let me know if works.

Comment: thanks. I will try this right away. Too bad that DataFrame is compiled and we can’t just settattr(pd, DataFrame, DataFrame2)

Comment: this doesn't work for me. I always get: AttributeError: module 'patched_pandas ' has no attribute 'read_csv'

Answer (score 0):

For maximum convenience I played around a little longer. I finally got it to work like this (not sure why the last line is necessary)

```
#patched_pandas.py
from pandas import *

class DataFrame2(pandas.DataFrame):
    def new_function(self):
        print("I exist")


patch_function = ['read_csv', 'read_json', 'read_html', 'read_clipboard', 'read_excel',
                  'read_hdf', 'read_feather', 'read_msgpack',
                  'read_stata', 'read_sas', 'read_pickle', 'read_sql']

for func in patch_function:
    orig_func = getattr(pandas, func)

    def patch(func):
        def patched(*args, **kwargs):
            return DataFrame2(func(*args, **kwargs))
        return patched

    setattr(pandas, func, patch(orig_func))

from pandas import *
```

and

```
#main.py (or wherever)
import patched_pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
df.new_function()
```